# What happened to new questions counts for filters on the Filtered Question page?

Tags: bug, tag-filters

When I was entering **Filtered Questions** page on the StackExchange, in the Select Filter area I could see the number of new questions related to given filter.

It was very useful to see, if there are any new messages for the given filter.

What has happened to that feature? Is it gone for good or only temporarily?

Comment: me too ;) Maybe add tag [tag:bug]?

Comment: @glennjackman I've added a bug tag but Fish removed that for unknown reason, without any explanation

Comment: Yes this is most likely a bug, @Fish shouldn't have removed the tag. (when it's obviously not a bug, or a dev, can do that, but this user is not a dev and it's really not obvious whether it is a bug or not)

Comment: Ah. Duly noted. Sorry about that.

Comment: ditto ... (deep sigh)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Looks like we are not going to have any feedback here :-(

Comment: Tell me about it... I fear that's the fate of most bug reports, but we just have to be patient. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm afraid that it is not a bug, its a feature ;-) . Probably classified as performance improvement.

Comment: Well, two of the best developers looked into it and found it's going deep, too deep for the limited time they have to spare on non-critical bugs. Guess we'll just have to live without those numbers.